# Instagram icon not showing up

Tags: html, css, icons, instagram

Instagram icon is not showing up on my website. I've tried and looked really carefully but I couldn't find the problem, I have re-typed it several times and looked up in google and here but still did'nt work. I hope one of you guys can help me out.

[Here you can see my code and css. Nothing wrong I guess?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zBRuy.png)

[And this is how it looks like on the internet.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SZxvk.png)

Instagram icon is not showing up :(

Answer (score 1):

A link would be nice, makes it easier to help :-)

It looks like the font that you are using does not have the IG icon in the glyph. Try switching to Font Awesome : https://www.w3schools.com/icons/tryit.asp?filename=tryicons_fa-instagram